# Native Libraries in Mediaplayer

Tags: android, media-player, native

where can I find the native libraries used in MediaPlayer class in android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the [code](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/tree/master/media) on Github's Android repo. For example, [JNI layer](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/media/jni/android_media_MediaPlayer.cpp) and [MediaPlayer](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/media/libmedia/IMediaPlayer.cpp) native class.